# Moment Generating Function - Cauchy Random Variable

Tags: probability, proof-verification, moment-generating-functions

I want to show that, for every $t\neq 0$, the moment generating function of the standard Cauchy distribution is equal to $+\infty$, i.e.

$$M_X(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{tx}}{1+x^2}dx = +\infty$$

I'm *really* rusty in term of probabilities and integrals, but here is my first try, could anyone validate (or not) this?
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{tx}}{1+x^2}dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{e^{tx}}{1+x^2}dx + \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{tx}}{1+x^2}dx \\
& \geq \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{(e^{x})^t}{1+x^2}dx\\
& \geq \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx\\
&= \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \arctan(x)\\
&= +\infty
\end{align*}

Comment: That last equality doesn't look right.

Comment: Indeed!! I went way too fast on that one.

Comment: The fact that the Cauchy distribution [does not have finite moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Explanation_of_undefined_moments) of order $\ge 1$ is an adequate argument for the nonexistence of the moment generating function.